# efficiently rotate 3d vector in plane of itself and another one

Tags: 3d, geometry

I wonder if a 3d-vector `a` may be rotated in a plane spanned by `a` and an normalized vector `b` by 90 degree more efficiently than straight forward doing (pseudo GLSL style):

```
a=normalize(a);
vec3 axis=cross(a,b);
c=rotate(identity,90,axis)*a;
```

Comment: Can we assume these are unit vectors? Because that does open up a simpler solution. If you first have to normalize them that would eat up some of the efficiency...

Comment: `b` would be already normalized. `a` usually is not.

Comment: edited question to get a normalized result too, which is what I like to have.

Comment: so it now is still wrong I guess, most rotate(..) functions will need already normalized axis... I think we can accept normalizing `a` before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a and b span a plane, they cannot be colinear. Thus there is a part of b that is at right angles to a. Call this b'

```
na = norm(a)
b' = b - ( dot(a,b)/na ) * A / na
Arot = b' * na / norm(b')
```

This give a rotation "towards" b. If you want to rotate "away", take a minus sign in the last line. This should take fewer instructions than arbitrary rotation.

If a is already normalized then `na==1` and it simplifies further:

```
b' = b - dot(a,b)* A
Arot = b' / norm(b')
```

Comment: It was a fun little thing to work out... Thanks for the challenge!